# k8s ingress HTTP response invalid for redirect

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I came across a very interesting situation. I am running a apache server inside a Docker container, running a [mediawiki](https://mediawiki.org) installation.

When I run `curl localhost:8081 -v`, I get a valid response. Also visiting the website in the browser redirects me to the main page as expected:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sun, 01 Nov 2020 05:18:33 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.24
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
< Expires: Sun, 01 Nov 2020 05:18:33 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Last-Modified: Sun, 01 Nov 2020 05:18:33 GMT
< Location: http://wiki.10.0.0.20.xip.io/wiki/Main_Page
< Connection: close
< Content-Encoding: none
< Content-Length: 0
< X-Request-Id: 76816afe025ea1c1ced4d30d
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<
* Closing connection 0
```

When on the other hand I make the request through the nginx ingress, I get the following:

```
*   Trying 10.0.0.20...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to wiki.10.0.0.20.xip.io (10.0.0.20) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: wiki.10.0.0.20.xip.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.19.1
< Date: Sun, 01 Nov 2020 05:25:49 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.24
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
< Expires: Sun, 01 Nov 2020 05:25:49 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Last-Modified: Sun, 01 Nov 2020 05:25:49 GMT
< Location: http://wiki.10.0.0.20.xip.io/wiki/Main_Page
< Content-Encoding: none
< X-Request-Id: d6457fbb4f7cc3d0003206eb
<
* Connection #0 to host wiki.10.0.0.20.xip.io left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

As you can see, the `Location` header is the same in both responses. The only difference in my eyes is the `Connection: keep-alive` header which is set to `close` by Apache. Is this forbidden for 301 results?

When I try to open the Page in Chrome/Safari, the pod server works correctly, but the ingress shows the `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error message without any further indication. Furthermore, passing any query param to the url, like `?a`, shows the start page correctly. This is most likely because any invalid URL is caught by mediawiki and redirected to the start page.

My ingress config is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: wiki.10.0.0.20.xip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mediawiki
                port:
                  number: 80
```

The kubernetes environment has been created via `minikube`. I am using the local NAT network adapter from VirtualBox. But also with a bridged network it is the same from another machine. You can see that the connection is established as I see the `301`. Also it routes to mediawiki/PHP, but then the response becomes invalid on the way.

I deployed the service as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mediawiki
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mediawiki
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30090
```

And the deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mediawiki
  labels:
    app: mediawiki
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mediawiki
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mediawiki
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mediawiki
        image: mediawiki
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: localsettings
          mountPath: "/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php"
          readOnly: true
          subPath: LocalSettings.php
        - name: logo
          mountPath: "/var/www/html/resources/assets/wiki.png"
          readOnly: true
          subPath: logo.png
      volumes:
        - name: localsettings
          configMap:
            name: localsettings
        - name: logo
          configMap:
            name: logo
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about your environment, its local environment? Its on any virtualization software? How did you deployed Nginx Ingress, using helm? Could you provide Deployment and Service YAMLs?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I provided the YAML's and further explanation.